# How to Integrate TinyMCE editor with php

Tags: php, tinymce, textarea

how do I integrate TinyMCE editor with php? I have downloaded the editor and put it in the js folder in my root directory. I have the following implementation in my code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        themes: "modern",   
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste moxiemanager"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"   
    });
    </script>
```

And here's where the text box area is:

```
     <textarea name="pageBody" id="pageBody" rows="4"></textarea>
```

When I view the webpage, the text editor is not showing.

Comment: This integration is in Javascript, not php !
have you any error in your javascript console ? (load your page in chrome, right click > element inspector > console)

Comment: try removing all plugins to plugins: [""], do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: I got this error when I checked the console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/trainingSite/administrator/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined adminTestPage.php:13
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Seems like your script path is wrong. Check it out.

Comment: Yes you're right. I have changed the script path and I'm faced with a new error.

http://localhost/trainingSite/js/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/plugin.min.js I don't have moxiemanager in the plugins folder. How can I get it? Searched through google and found out it's a premium tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the moxiemanager from your plugins: entry. (last entry)

Comment: I have removed it and it's working just fine. Thanks a bunch! One more thing...I can't add pictures and files using the text editor. I would have to know the file path before uploading. Any ideas on adding the moxie plugin?

Answer (score 1):

/* JS */

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/d5xkm37lhhdhglxdlbmt0eg9ug9mkwhcne5zrfikmlq7qxoi/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

function textEditor() {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '.texteditor',
        plugins: 'image code, casechange, permanentpen, checklist, pageembed, formatpainter, table advtable, media, autoresize, paste, lists, searchreplace, emoticons, fullscreen, autolink link',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | casechange | formatselect | pageembed | permanentpen | bold italic | checklist numlist bullist | alignleft aligncenter alignright forecolor backcolor | table advtable searchreplace | link image media | code | rotateleft rotateright | imageoptions | quicklink blockquote | emoticons',
        // toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link code ",
        // menubar: true
        image_title: true,
        /* enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs*/
        automatic_uploads: true,
        file_picker_types: 'image',
        /* and here's our custom image picker*/
        file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
            input.onchange = function () {
                var file = this.files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                    /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), {title: file.name});
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
            input.click();
        },
        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    });
}
```

/* HTML */

```
<textarea class="form-control texteditor" name="content" rows="2"></textarea>
```